# Check multiple rows in one dataframe present on another dataframe using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My requirement is to check whether all the rows in one dataframe present on another. Here I have two dataframe shown as below:

dfActual

[image: dfActual]

dfExpected

[image: dfExpected]

Here i want to check whether all the rows in dfExpected present on dfActual, if all present it should return true else false.
I have tried the below solution:

```
dfActual['Bool_col'] = (dfActual.merge(dfExpected,
                                         how='left',
                                         indicator=True)
                               .eval('_merge == "both"'))
```

But it always returns false. Could anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Guess No. 1:** You want a new row that identifies whether it occurs in another data frame. Then, you could do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'AAA'],
    'AGE': [24] * 6,
    'LIMIT': [2] * 6
})

df_sub = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME': ['AAA', 'BBB'],
    'AGE': [24] * 2,
    'LIMIT': [2] * 2
})

df['check'] = np.isin(df.values, df_sub.values).all(axis=1)
df


------------------------------
    NAME  AGE   LIMIT   check
0   AAA   24    2       True
1   BBB   24    2       True
2   CCC   24    2       False
3   CCC   24    2       False
4   DDD   24    2       False
5   AAA   24    2       True
------------------------------
```

**Guess No. 2:**
If you just want to check, whether one data frame occurs in another, you could use this:

```py
df_sub.isin(df).all(axis=1).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me correctly you can see in my attached image.Kindly check your DataFrame making mistake any where else

[image: Result]

You comment that column then also result is ok see this image.
[image: Result after changing data]

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
actual_list = dfActual.to_numpy().tolist()
expected_list = dfExpected.to_numpy().tolist()
all_rows_present = np.all([True if sub_list in  actual_list else False 
                for sub_list in expected_list])
```